# Can't install Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) and 13.10 (64 bit) along-side Windows 7 and windows 8 from USB

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 13.10, windows

I use laptop Acer Aspire 4738. I try many solutions: 
**First**: I have Windows 7 - 64 bit, want install Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit (`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`, use USB creat tools: `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6.exe`) along-side, but can't install.

**Second**: I have Windows 8.1 - 64 bit, want install Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit (`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`, use USB creat tools: `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6.exe`) along-side, but can't install.

**Third**: I have Windows 8.1 - 64 bit, want install Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit (`ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`, use USB creat tools: `unetbootin-windows-608.exe`) along-side, but can't install.

**Forth**: I have Windows 8.1 - 64 bit, want install Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit (`ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso`, use USB creat tools: `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6.exe`) along-side, but can't install. My intent is install version 13.10, then update to 14.04 LTS

**Fifth**: I have Windows 8.1 - 64 bit, want install Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit (`ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso`, use USB creat tools: `unetbootin-windows-608.exe`) along-side, but can't install.

... and so forth...
One year ago and many times ago, I install Windows 8 64 bit and Ubuntu 13.10 normally, and  no problem. This time, When I install ubuntu from USB boot, there are 3 options, I try First option, but **Install progress don't remember install state**.

Please help me, I don't try "Install Ubuntu replace Windows", I want install Ubuntu along-side Windows. Any ideas are appreciated.(My CD/DVD driver can't burn disc, I have only USB)

Update:
I try:`H:\wubi.exe --force-wubi` to **install Ubuntu 13.10 inside Windows**, successful, but I really don't like this (want dual-boot, alongside). I have been disabled Hibernate.
[image]

[image]

folow these ansers, I checked:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean "can't install"? please explain: why can't you install?

Comment: @mchid, Can't install Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) and 13.10 (64 bit) along-side Windows 7 and windows 8 from USB

Comment: Donhuvy, Wubi will still install etc. it just does not write an entry to the MBR, thus on boot you do not recognize it. If you want to dual boot, within Window's make a partition, boot to a live USB, select `something else` and then format only the partition you want. This will let Linux write to the MBR that window's is using, and thus allows you to boot to both.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not have enough rep to add comments**

Please refer to this question here on a detailed guide on [installing Ubuntu alongside Window's 8.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Now with the methods you have stated are all good and well, but you have not mentioned why you cannot install. Are you not able to get to the menu to install, does  it install and not recognize etc? If you'd like, have a look at this [post on my blog-](http://dudedoyouevenubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-windows-8-x64-laptop/) (or this [phenomenal link)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) it should demonstrate an easy guide to dual-boot with Window's 8.

Now I am in no way, shape or form an expert on Linux (so the post I did is probably really incorrect), so I will re-inforce you r[ead up on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) and add more details on the issue you are having with your install. Sorry I could not comment, I know this isn't an "answer".

Comment: @donhvy The CMD LET not supported means you do not need to worry about Secure Boot. If this is the case, and you want to dual boot, can you shrink your HDD, make a partition and install to that. It will perform the same actions as WUBI.

Comment: Thank you, I have been formatted entire hard disk. The problem is needing at least 2 **primary** partions.

Comment: I'm sorry. What's the problem there?